# Is Python's zip() function executed in a multi-processing way?

Tags: python

I'm wondering if Python's zip() function is executed in a multi-processing way, or it is actually done by a single thread, and then simply combines the results together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it does not involve multiprocessing at all.  And neither does it involve threading at all, zip is acting  entirely in the current thread.

However, the zip is *lazy* (in the current version of Python), meaning elements will not be evaluated until you iterate a zip instance.

Comment: [The source for `zip.next()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5746510b7aef423fa4afc92b2abb919307b1dbb9/Python/bltinmodule.c#L2645) backs this up, showing that it grabs one item from each iterable to build each tuple as it is needed.  It's just simple iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Nope it is a single process .

It is done in a single thread